# Java 4 operator calculator using switch not working

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

When i run it, nothing happens. Whats weird to me is how the systemoutprintln asking what you want to do doesnt work either. The scanner is called earlier in it by the way. If im doing something completely wrong please tell me :) Any help would be tremendous.

```
Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
String operator = scanner3.nextLine();

System.out.println("What do you want to do? (add, subtract, multiply, or divide?)");

switch (operator){

case "add": System.out.println("Enter number one ");
    Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double addnum1 = scanner4.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double addnum2 = scanner5.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( addnum1 + addnum2);
    break;

case "subtract": System.out.println("Enter number one");
    Scanner scanner7 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double subnum1 = scanner7.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    Scanner scanner8 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double subnum2 = scanner8.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( subnum1 - subnum2 );
    break;

case "multiply": System.out.println("Enter number one");
    Scanner scanner9 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double mulnum1 = scanner9.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    Scanner scanner10 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double mulnum2 = scanner10.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( mulnum1 * mulnum2 );
    break;
case "divide": System.out.println("Enter number one");
    Scanner scanner11 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double divnum1 = scanner11.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    Scanner scanner12 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double divnum2 = scanner12.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( divnum1 / divnum2 );
    break;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `nextLine()` at the top, so it's expecting input (even before printing anything).

Comment: Why on earth are you declaring 9-10 scanners??

Answer (score 0):

the first printing

```
System.out.println("What do you want to do? (add, subtract, multiply or divide?)");
```

was after the

```
.nextLine()
```

so your program expects the input before printing the first message.

you can use same scanner for all cases, much better and cleaner code.

```
Scanner scanner_all = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What do you want to do? (add, subtract, multiply or divide?)");
String operator = scanner_all.nextLine();

switch (operator){

case "add": 
    System.out.println("Enter number one ");
    double addnum1 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    double addnum2 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( addnum1 + addnum2);
    break;

case "subtract": 
    System.out.println("Enter number one");
    double subnum1 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    double subnum2 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( subnum1 - subnum2 );
    break;

case "multiply": 
    System.out.println("Enter number one");
    double mulnum1 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    double mulnum2 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( mulnum1 * mulnum2 );
    break;
case "divide": 
    System.out.println("Enter number one");
    double divnum1 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter number two ");
    double divnum2 = scanner_all.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("the answer is: ");
    System.out.println( divnum1 / divnum2 );
    break;
}
```